# Remapping Unaccented Vowels into Accented Ones using AHK (AutohotKey) - 2 ISSUES & REQUESTS

Tags: autohotkey, diacritics

thanks in advance for your valuable and diligent assistance !

I have a little Qwerty laptop and I'm trying to remap unaccented vowels into accented ones using AHK (AutohotKey).

ISSUE #1:
For example, for the letter e, if I press "e" and "right arrow" altogether, I should get "é"; and if I do the same combination with Capslock activated, I should get "É". So I used the following script:

e & Right::
if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "t")
send É
else
send é
return

It works !... Except that the "e" key is no longer functional after this.

REQUEST #1:
How do you preserve the "e" key in the previous script ?

ISSUE #2:
Instead of repeating the same (corrected) previous script for each vowel to be accentuated in upper and lower case (all vowels {a,e,i,o,u}) ...

REQUEST #2:
Can you create for me an optimized generic script, using this set of vowels as variables, such as:

- If Capslock is activated and I simultaneously press a Vowel and:

  - LEFT => this Vowel in Upper-case with Acute Accent (')
  - RIGHT => this Vowel in Upper-case with Grave Accent (`)
  - UP => this Vowel in Upper-case with Circumflex Accent (ˆ)
  - DOWN => this Vowel in Upper-case with Tremae/Diaeresis Accent (¨)
- If Capslock is not activated and I simultaneously press a vowel and:

  - LEFT => this Vowel in Lower-case with Acute Accent (')
  - RIGHT => this Vowel with Grave Accent (`)
  - UP => this Vowel in Lower-case with Circumflex Accent (ˆ)
  - DOWN => this Vowel in Lower-case with Tremae/Diaeresis Accent (¨)

Comment: Try something like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75935154/3419297).

Comment: check here for a working [example](https://superuser.com/a/1597282/456981)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial goal was to use my QWERTY keyboard as-is while being able to quickly generate accented vowels with a 2-key hotkeys (a Vowel & an Arrow Key). After digesting the AHK v2 documentation, I wrote the following script which even exceeds my expectations...

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Warn All

;I. ACCENTED VOWELS

; CORRESPONDENCE TABLE

;           SECOND-BUTTON:  a, A, o, O, e, E, i, I, u, U
;       INDEX NUMBERS:      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
;   FIRST-BUTTON:   
;           [RIGHT]         á, Á, ó, Ó, é, É, í, Í, ú, Ú   
;           [LEFT]          à, À, ò, Ò, è, È, ì, Ì, ù, Ù   
;           [UP]            â, Â, ô, Ô, ê, Ê, î, Î, û, Û   
;           [DOWN]          ä, Ä, ö, Ö, ë, Ë, ï, Ï, ü, Ü   

VowelKeys_Str := "a,A,o,O,e,E,i,I,u,U"   
VowelKeys_Arr := StrSplit(VowelKeys_Str, ",")   


Acute_Arr := ["á", "Á", "ó", "Ó", "é", "É", "í", "Í", "ú", "Ú"]
Grave_Arr := ["à", "À", "ò", "Ò", "è", "È", "ì", "Ì", "ù", "Ù"]
Cflex_Arr := ["â", "Â", "ô", "Ô", "ê", "Ê", "î", "Î", "û", "Û"]
Trema_Arr := ["ä", "Ä", "ö", "Ö", "ë", "Ë", "ï", "Ï", "ü", "Ü"]

; For Acute Vowels : Press [RIGHT] Button with the corresponding [Vowel] Key (Lowercase or Uppercase)

Right::
{
    IH := InputHook("C T0.4", "", VowelKeys_Str)
    IH.start()
    IH.wait()
    KEY := IH.Match
    Loop
    {
        if A_Index > 10
        {
            SendInput "{Right}"
            break
        }
        if VowelKeys_Arr[A_Index] == KEY
        {
            SendInput Acute_Arr[A_Index]
            break
        }
    }
}

; For Grave Vowels : Press [LEFT] Button with the corresponding [Vowel] Key (Lowercase or Uppercase)

Left::
{
    IH := InputHook("C T0.4", "", VowelKeys_Str)
    IH.start()
    IH.wait()
    KEY := IH.Match
    Loop
    {
        if A_Index > 10
        {
            SendInput "{Left}"
            break
        }
        if VowelKeys_Arr[A_Index] == KEY
        {
            SendInput Grave_Arr[A_Index]
            break
        }
    }
}

; For Circumflex Vowels : Press [UP] Button with the corresponding [Vowel] Key (Lowercase or Uppercase)

Up::
{
    IH := InputHook("C T0.4", "", VowelKeys_Str)
    IH.start()
    IH.wait()
    KEY := IH.Match
    Loop
    {
        if A_Index > 10
        {
            SendInput "{Up}"
            break
        }
        if VowelKeys_Arr[A_Index] == KEY
        {
            SendInput Cflex_Arr[A_Index]
            break
        }
    }
}

; For Trema Vowels : Press [DOWN] Button with the corresponding [Vowel] Key (Lowercase or Uppercase)

Down::
{
    IH := InputHook("C T0.4", "", VowelKeys_Str)
    IH.start()
    IH.wait()
    KEY := IH.Match
    Loop
    {
        if A_Index > 10
        {
            SendInput "{Down}"
            break
        }
        if VowelKeys_Arr[A_Index] == KEY
        {
            SendInput Trema_Arr[A_Index]
            break
        }
    }
}

;II. SYMBOLS (AND SOME SPECIAL LETTERS)

; CORRESPONDENCE TABLE
;           SECOND-BUTTON:  a, A, o, O, c, C, e, d, p, y, n, r, s, b, v, w, q, h, x, t, z
;       INDEX NUMBERS:      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
;   FIRST-BUTTON:
;             [END]         æ, Æ, œ, Œ, ç, Ç, €, $, £, ¥, &, @, §, ¦, |, !, ?, ", *, °, º

LetterKeys_Str := "a,A,o,O,c,C,e,d,p,y,n,r,s,b,v,w,q,h,x,t,z"
LetterKeys_Arr := StrSplit(LetterKeys_Str, ",")


Symbols_Arr := ["æ", "Æ", "œ", "Œ", "ç", "Ç", "€", "$", "£", "¥", "`&", "@", "§", "¦", "|", "{!}", "`?", "`"", "*", "°", "º"]

; For Symbols : Press [END] Button with the corresponding [Letter] Key (Lowercase or Uppercase)

End::
{
    IH := InputHook("C T0.4", "", LetterKeys_Str)
    IH.start()
    IH.wait()
    KEY := IH.Match
    Loop
    {
        if A_Index > 21
        {
            SendInput "{End}"
            break
        }
        if LetterKeys_Arr[A_Index] == KEY
        {
            SendInput Symbols_Arr[A_Index]
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#1 You have to use [{BLIND}](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#blind), and *e, because you have to handling e+any key combination.

```
*e::
    Switch A_ThisHotkey GetKeyState("RIGHT", "p") GetKeyState("CapsLock", "t")
    {
        Case "*e11" :
            send É
        Case "*e10" :
            send é
        Case "*e01" :
            sendraw E
        Case "*e00" :
            send {BLIND}e
        Default :
            send {BLIND}%A_ThisHotkey%
    }
return
```

#2
Why dont you use simply the native windows [accent keyboard combo](https://www.ut.edu/academics/college-of-arts-and-letters/department-of-languages-and-linguistics/typing-accented-characters),  instead of remapping buttons?

Comment: Your script is interesting (using the Switch method) but it's definitely not working on AHK V2. I'd like to get accented vowels remapped in associations with the arrow buttons so as to have a faster way to type accented vowels, in lowercase or uppercase. However I will try to work around your Switch script to find out how to make it work.

Comment: I didn't test with ahk 2 because I've been using ahk for 15 years and I have so many scripts that I didn't bother to rewrite them all according to the new syntax. If it doesn't work, it can basically be because the character encoding of the script is not UTF8-with Signature, the commands should be equivalent.